# Using views_embed_views() to generate content for an email message. How can I get it to insert images and urls correctly for this purpose?

Tags: views, emails, theming

I am using views_embed_views() to generate content for an email message. How can I get it to insert images and urls correctly for this purpose?

Or, asked another way, how can I put the contents of a view into an html email body?

Comment: Are you already sending HTML emails with images and links ? 
or is this question two fold 1) how do I prorammatically send HTML emails and 2) how do I insert the out put of a view into an email ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [hook_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7) and [drupal_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) to send out e-mail. drupal_mail at the place you want to send to mail, eg. hook_cron. And hook_mail to set the content. Use drupal_mail to send parameters to hook_mail.

As for the images, make sure that you use absolute url's in views (setting on the image field).